# Regex to match a string with a slash

Tags: java, regex

I want to match a string containing slashes in Java. I have the following code:

```
String exclude = "some/class/in/package/*.class";
String className = "some/class/in/package/TheClass.class";
boolean value = className.matches(exclude);
System.out.println(value);

>false
```

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Valid class names must start with a letter so it could reasonably be

```
"some/class/in/package/[A-Za-z].*\\.class"
```

But then you probably ought to put in valid characters for the rest

```
"some/class/in/package/[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*\\.class"
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I had forgotten the '.' before '*'

```
String exclude = "some/class/in/package/.*.class";
```

Comment: Also might want to escape that `.`, before the class so it is literal.